# Kill all task started by object : Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, background

I have class. In which I am running some background task (using performselectorInBackground), when these function complete in the end I am adding a subview. But in some case I am releasing and setting nil the object of class before completing the background task.
Event then these background task was not killed and update my UI with adding subview.

How I kill the all the task started by the object.

Answer (score 0):

`performSelectorInBackground` is a set and forget method. You can't cancel them. However you have two choices. You can move over to `dispatch_*` type commands. Or you can use a boolean in your background loop to check if it should cancel itself. Then just set that bool to YES when you need to cancel it and on the next loop you can return or something along those lines.

Comment: `NSOperationQueue` is a better choice for canceling tasks. Just have the object create a queue that all operations are added to and call `[myQueue cancelAllOperations];` when they should all be cancelled. The operations that are already running will however have to check if they are cancelled using `[self isCancelled]` to stop executing once they have started.

Comment: Yea David is right. Forgot about NSOperationQueue. Its normally beyond the scope of my need but it is definitely better than the lazy boolean method.

Comment: But in my case there is no other operation in queue, may I have only one operation which is running in background. and I want to cancel my current running task. Can I kill the running task using dispatch_*

Comment: Yes you can using dispatch but its much more complicated. If you only have a single function running in the background I suggest you go for the very easy boolean method.